Unexpected error when using gganimate and ggplot2
I am looking to animate a map of values plotted on a world map (from rnaturalearth) across years. I have downloaded rnaturalearth data and joined it with my data set (three variables: one of the country code to join it with the rnaturalearth data, one of the value for each country, and one for the year). I am able to join these two datasets as normal:
baseBorderMap <- 
  ne_countries(returnclass = 'sf') # Returns world country polygons as sf class
baseBorderMap["51", "iso_a2_eh"] <- "NM" # Renames Namibia country code
baseBorderMap["175", "iso_a2_eh"] <- "XK" # Renames Kosovo country code
aniData <- baseBorderMap %>% right_join(countryYearMam, by = "iso_a2_eh") # Adds counts to map data (maybe something to do with fill needing data with borders?)
aniData <- filter(aniData, !is.na(specimens)) # Remove records with no specimens

I am able to plot the map, ignoring the year data, using a normal ggplot2 function:
mammalYear <- ggplot(data = aniData) + # Plots map
  geom_sf(data = aniData, lwd = 0) +
  geom_sf(data = aniData, aes(fill = log(specimens)), lwd = 0.3) + # Sets fill colour based on specimens from mydata2
  #ggtitle("(b)") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

I receive an error once I add gganimate functions to the plot and try to visualise it or use the animate() function.
timelapse_mammalYear <- mammalYear +
  transition_states(year,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 1) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()

> timelapse_mammalYear
Error in vapply(from, nrow, integer(1)) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[8]]) result is length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In max(area_diff) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

What does this error mean, and how can I modify my data to properly work with these functions to I can animate my map?
Second edit: There are no NAs in any of the columns.
>dput(head(countryYearMam, 5))
structure(list(iso_a2_eh = c("AD", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AD"), year = c(1930L, 
1950L, 1962L, 1965L, 1968L), specimens = c(1L, 12L, 24L, 14L, 
3L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Year: min = 1793, max = 2020
Specimens: min = 1, max = 2601

I think I know what's causing the issue but I'll need to see a copy of your countryYearMam data to confirm. Please update your question with a sample of your countryYearMam data. You can usedput(countryYearMam) and copy the result into your question.

Sorry, I should have mentioned you can do something like dput(head(countryYearMam, 5)) if you data are large. Reduce 5 if that is still too large. It's necessary to have the entire dput() result e.g. structure(...). Also, are NA values only present in the specimens column, or can there be NA values in other columns? Please also mention the min and max values of year and specimens.

@LTyrone, I've added those extra details. Thank you!

I could not reproduce your issue, but potential causes include:

problems with your countryYearMam data
your package versions/R environment
bugs with gganimate

Without your full dataset, I cannot guarantee this will solve your specific issue. However, here is a repex with some improvements to your approach that should work with your actual data. It uses an example countryYearMam dataset with 29,259 rows. Some points to consider:

The ne_countries() object you created does not contain all administrative areas present in your data e.g. Andorra, so a more detailed version is used
In your ggplot(), you call aniData twice but only one of them has any aes() applied. This is an unnecessary overhead, so baseBorderMap is used instead.
There are known bugs with gganimate. I can't say for sure whether you're encountering a bug, but ne_countries() has triggered issues in the past

Load packages and generate data:
library(rnaturalearth) # 1.0.1
library(dplyr) # 1.1.4
library(sf) # 1.0.15
library(gganimate) # 1.0.8 with ggplot2 3.5.0

# Create world map sf: note addition of scale argument
baseBorderMap <- ne_countries(scale = 50, returnclass = 'sf') %>%
  st_set_crs(NA)

# Correct ISO2 country codes: note substitution of iso_a2_eh column
baseBorderMap[which(baseBorderMap$sovereignt == "Namibia"), "iso_a2"] <- "NM"
baseBorderMap[which(baseBorderMap$sovereignt == "Kosovo"), "iso_a2"] <- "XK"

# Simplify geometries for faster plotting
baseBorderMap <- baseBorderMap %>%
  st_simplify(preserveTopology = FALSE,
              dTolerance = .001)

# Create example countryYearMam df
countryYearMam <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = 3))
colnames(countryYearMam) <- c("iso_a2", "year", "specimens")

set.seed(1)
for(i in sort(baseBorderMap$iso_a2)) {
  
  j <- sample(30:227, 1)
  k <- rep(i, j)
  m <- sort(sample(1793:2020, j))
  n <- sample(1:2601, j)
  tmp <- data.frame(iso_a2 = k, year = m, specimens = n)
  countryYearMam <- rbind(countryYearMam, tmp)
  
}

Join sf data to countryYearMam:
# Join countryYearMam to map sf and filter NAs
aniData <- baseBorderMap %>% 
  right_join(countryYearMam, by = "iso_a2") %>%
  filter(!is.na(specimens)) %>% # included for completeness, no NAs were generated in sample df above
  select(continent, iso_a2, year, specimens)

Generate plot:
mammalYear <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = baseBorderMap, colour = "grey75") +
  geom_sf(data = aniData,
          aes(fill = log(specimens)),
          lwd = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

timelapse_mammalYear <- mammalYear +
  transition_states(year,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 1) +
  labs(title = "Year: {closest_state}") + # For illustrative purposes
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()

Generate .gif: note this animate() script took ~53 minutes to run on a relatively low-spec PC
anim <- animate(timelapse_mammalYear, 
        renderer = gifski_renderer(), 
        height = 5,
        width = 8, 
        units = "cm",
        fps = 1, 
        duration = 228, 
        end_pause = 2, 
        res = 100)

anim


